# Xamarin.Forms Dynamic Link Library Debugging Issue

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We have a Xamarin Forms project, in the MainActivity of which we connect dynamically the class library. Before connecting, this library is imported from the server into the `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`, which is the `/data/data/com.companyname.projectname/files` folder on the android device. Next, using reflection, we create an object of type IApplicationController:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom (localLibFilePath);
Type [] types = asm.GetTypes ();
var type = types.SingleOrDefault (t => t.GetInterface (nameof (IApplicationController))! = null);
var App = Activator.CreateInstance (type) as IApplicationController;
```

Then we launch the application from dll using objects (Xamarin.Forms.Application) App:

```
LoadApplication ((Xamarin.Forms.Application) App);
```

In the App : Application class of the plug-in library, set a breakpoint and start debugging.
After deploying to the device, the application stops at the line `var App = Activator.CreateInstance (type) as IApplicationController;` and then doesn't go into the library. In this case, the pointer on this line takes the form like this:

[xamarin dll debug issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzWAi.png)

The library is loaded onto the device with a .pdb file.

The pluggable library project is in the same solution with the Droid app.

The Resolved pending breakpoint at 'App.xaml.cs: 25,1' to void AppBase.App..ctor () [0x00008] line appears in the Output window.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: You mean the breakpoint does not work? Can you try to delete obj/bin folder and re-add your breakpoint again?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes, I have done it, but the issue stil exists.

Comment: Can you please update your visual-studio and try again? I find the problem in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/998764/xamarin-ios-breakpoints-not-working-in-a-custom-nu.html) is similar with yours.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I just updated my VS from 16.7.6 to 16.7.7 and it didn't help.

Comment: Does the breakpoint work in other lines?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Breakpoints work only within main project. But in the dll don't.

Comment: Can you please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-dll-projects?view=vs-2019#vxtskdebuggingdllprojectsbuildingadebugversion) about Debug DLLs in Visual Studio?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes, I do. I read this document and I didn't see there something new for myself. And more, I have tried to repeat this experiment with .net core console project and I could debug external dll without any problems. So, I can suggest that this issue is only related on Xamarin project. Sorry for my English.

Comment: If you are sure that this issue is only related on Xamarin project, you can open is an issue in Github for more help.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Ok. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem. If you find a solution, you can share here.